# HttpsURLConnection with IP issue

Tags: connection, ip, httpsurlconnection

```
String currentUrl = "https://www.test.com/";
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) (currentUrl.openConnection())
```

If i use domain, everything works perfectly.

However, if i use the ip address of the domain,

```
String currentUrl = "https://123.123.123.123:443/";
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) (currentUrl.openConnection());
```

problem occurs, i got the `SSLPeerUnverifiedException(Hostname 123.123.123.123 not verified` Exception, and the request failed.

In order to fix this problem, i just provide a HostnameVerifier

```
conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        String host  = "www.test.com";

        return HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier().verify(host, session);
    }
});
```

in addition, i have to solve the same problem of SNI situation.

so i provide a custom SSLSocketFactory

```
MySSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new MySSLSocketFactory(conn);
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);

public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory{

    private HttpsURLConnection conn;

    public HalleySSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException,
            UnknownHostException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost,
            int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port,
            InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket plainSocket, String host, int port,
            boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        String peerHost = this.conn.getRequestProperty("Host");

        if (peerHost == null)
            peerHost = host;

        InetAddress address = plainSocket.getInetAddress();
        if (autoClose) {
            plainSocket.close();
        }

        SSLCertificateSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLCertificateSocketFactory) SSLCertificateSocketFactory
                .getDefault(0);
        SSLSocket ssl = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory
                .createSocket(address, port);


        ssl.setEnabledProtocols(ssl.getSupportedProtocols());

        // set up SNI before the handshake
        try {
            java.lang.reflect.Method setHostnameMethod = ssl.getClass()
                    .getMethod("setHostname", String.class);
            setHostnameMethod.invoke(ssl, peerHost);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FileLog.w(TAG, "SNI not useable", e);
        }

        return ssl;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it still has another problem,
it can't reuse the connection any more, which means every request have to tcp handshake and ssl handshake and it will cost a lot of time.

So Here is my question,
is there anyway to solve the direct IP request problem with HttpsUrlConnection?

if no, how can i reuse the connection according to what i mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

   @Override
   public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
         return true;
    }

});
```